# Detect a Virtual Machine on my Wifi?

Tags: wifi, virtualization, detection, vmware

Is there a way to detect whether a machine connected to my wifi is a physical machine or a virtual machine?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can look at their MAC address. For example, by default, VirtualBox begins theirs MAC address by 08002xxxx.

The lists of couple address MAC - constructors
https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/461260

Comment: That's a good point. But it doesn't take much at all for someone to change their MAC on a VM.

Comment: May be a good starting point, though, it also won't help if the VM is using NAT.